# How can i setup connected VMs on Windows Azure with 2 different regions

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I gone through official announcement of [General availability of Virtual Machine on Windows Azure](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/16/windows-azure-general-availability-of-infrastructure-as-a-service-iaas.aspx). so i would like to move one of my client's production app on this. Requirement to set up this app on 2 different regions as below

Basically we have two demographics from Australia and Turkey from where people will be accessing the server, So we need two web servers one from Australia and another from Europe

**- 2 Web servers with Window server 2008 r2**

**- Separate Database server with SQL server**

**- One Load balancer**

**Queries**

**1)** What data centers are best suited for above regions? 
**2)** we are not concerned about up-time instead we are concerned about performance at locale
   based so to run application on 1 VM is okay? 
**3)** In which region database should be hosted so both web server can access smoothly 
   regardless of performance issue. what should be region of it? 
**4)** Can we setup load balancing such a way for one url it would transfer request to 
   Australian server and for other transfer request to European server?
**5)** I have calculated price with

- 2 VM (small) for to host window server
- 1 vm (medium) to host sql server
- 35 GB bandwidth
- support for developer and it would cost me **around $300**,

Do I need to consider other pricing apart from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that you'd get more performance improvements by having one SQL database server and one web server that are in the same data centre, than have two web servers close to your customers both accessing the same DB.  There is going to be more communication between the web servers and the DB than there will be between the clients and the web servers.  You can then choose which set of customers you most want to keep happy and then choose the data centre close to them.  If you want to keep your Australian customers happy, then you have another choice, because for cities  in NSW that have access to the Southern Cross Cable, they get better response times from US data centres than they do from the asian ones.

Answer (score 1):

As for data-centers best suited, I suggest using 
1. Australia - South-East Asia
2. Turkey - West Europe/North Europe

Now for the other question....
1. if you are looking at performance at locale...then you should look for setting up Windows Azure Traffic Manager (Performance-based)...this will give you best performance based on closest hosted service....
2. Windows Azure Traffic Manager (Round-robin-based) will serve the expectation of one request to Australia and second to Europe.
Note: you can set either of the above two but not both. It is different from load-balancing which works within a region (Read more...[Azure VM load balancing vs Traffic Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546554/azure-vm-load-balancing-vs-traffic-manager))

There are other cost like transaction cost, storage cost, etc....I suggest you read Microsoft Azure cost model for details. (Read more...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx)

Bear in mind, VMs can recycle...you can also explore cloud services (web roles) for your requirements.